# Insert and retrieve user using SHA1 hash value in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sha1

I want to store (insert) and get (retrieve) a password with SHA1 hash algorithm as it is better than storing passwords in plain text. When inserting into the `users` table in my database, the SHA1 hash is inserted, however upon login it was not successful. Do I need to modify my function codes in my Javascript file?

I am using a HTML Login Form with POST Method.

This calls for the execution of the SQL codes in my function file.

```
function authenticate(request, respond) {
var input_username = request.body.username; // username from user input
var input_password = request.body.password; // password from user input
var msg = "";

// Call the getLoginDetails function from DB
DB.getLoginDetails(input_username, function(error, result) {

    if (error) {
        respond.json(error);
    } else {
        // If user can be found, result has one record
        if (result.length > 0) {
            if (input_password == result[0].password) {
                msg = "Successful.";
                console.log(msg);
            } else {
                msg = "Failed.";
                console.log(msg);
            }
        } else { // If user not found, result has no record
            msg = "User not found!";
        }
```

**Before changes(DB.js) file.**

```
insertData(user, callback) {

        var sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`,`username`,`password`) VALUES(?,?,?)";

        db.query(sql, [user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()], callback)
    }



    getLoginDetails(user, callback) {

        var sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        db.query(sql, [user], callback);
    }
```

**After making changes (DB.js) file**

```
    //Insert user with SHA1 algorithm
    insertData(user, callback) {

        var sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`,`username`,`password`) VALUES(?,?,SHA1(?))";

        db.query(sql, [user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()], callback)
    }


    //Login with SHA1 algorithm
    getLoginDetails(user, callback) {

        var sql = "SELECT SHA1(password) FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        db.query(sql, [user], callback);
    }
```

Comment: I rolled back your question to the original version. If you want to highlight additional things you tried, add an update to the end of your question.

Comment: SHA1, particularly if unsalted, is not at all adequate as a password hash.  https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/32112

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

```
var sql = "SELECT SHA1(password) FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Here, you're re-hashing what is already stored as a SHA1 hash in the database. That should just be:

```
var sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Then, on the password verification side, you're not hashing the input password when doing the comparison, so you're comparing a raw password (input by the user) to a SHA1 hash (retrieved from the database).

You'll need to include a function that performs a SHA1 hash (for example [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1)), and use that to hash the input password:

```
var sha1 = require('sha1');

// ...

if (result.length > 0) {
    if (sha1(input_password) == result[0].password) {
        // success
    } else {
        // failure
    }
}

// ...
```

On a side note, storing a hash is obviously better than storing a raw password, but SHA1 might be a little weak. It might be worth looking into something like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: I get `Error: Cannot find module 'sha1'` after making the changes. I am using a Node.js Web Server

Comment: Have you installed the module? `npm install sha1 --save`

Comment: Ok have installed the module, now I'm getting failed to login. Have updated the codes i'm using above.

Comment: First of all, don't rewrite your question, it loses all meaning then. Second, all the building blocks are there. Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I have made the changes to my function file here: https://pastebin.com/CMTLC6Bk and removed the extra hashing in DB.getLoginDetails. I have also tried restarting the server. The plain text method still works fine.

Comment: I can't debug it for you. A couple of `console.log()` statements to compare the values you're getting from the database with the values you calculate in your method should go a long way to pinpointing the exact location of the problem.